# Python tkinter - cloning root window properties and applying them to top level windows

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to create multiple nearly same looking windows without copy/paste all  window properties in every function.

```
def child_window():
    childwindow.geometry("400x800")

def window_one():
    childwindow = Toplevel(root)
    childwindow.title("title window one")
    child_window()

def window_two():
    childwindow = Toplevel(root)
    childwindow.title("title window two")
    child_window()
```

The code doesn't work as the childwindow won't take over the geometry property out of the general function child_window.
Is there any possible way to copy the design to all windows without putting the whole code in every single function.

Comment: Your `child_window()` function does not know about the `childwindow` toplevel window. This is for 2 reasons. Both functions are only working in the local namespace and thus don't share an info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the `Toplevel` object to the `child_window` function, you can use the object to directly set the geometry of that `Toplevel` window (also please don't reuse variable names):

```
def child_window(window):
    window.geometry("400x800")

def window_one():
    childwindow = Toplevel(root)
    childwindow.title("title window one")
    child_window(childwindow)

def window_two():
    childwindow = Toplevel(root)
    childwindow.title("title window two")
    child_window(childwindow)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code needlessly repeats itself and fails the [DRY code principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), here is solution that fixes the issue and follows the principal.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

def main():
    root = Tk()

    tops = list()
    for i in range(2):
        tops.append(same_top(root, 'title window ' + str(i)))

    mainloop()


def same_top(root, toptitle):
    child = Toplevel(root)
    child.title(toptitle)
    child.geometry("400x800")

    return child


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Your problem is that your child function does not know who `childwindow` is, if you would pass `childwindow` to the geometry function then it would work.

Your code fixed:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

def main():
    root = Tk()

    window_one(root)
    window_two(root)

    mainloop()


def child_window(childwindow):
    childwindow.geometry("400x800")

def window_one(root):
    childwindow = Toplevel(root)
    childwindow.title("title window one")
    child_window(childwindow)

def window_two(root):
    childwindow = Toplevel(root)
    childwindow.title("title window two")
    child_window(childwindow)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with fhdrsdg on his solution however I would change one thing.
Instead of the function holding a single set value for size have that function check the size of the root window first and then apply the same size to the toplevel window.

Your main issue can be solved with a few methods.
One method is to pass the toplevel window to the function responsible for assigning geometry. You can also build a class (IMO the best option for various reason) and you can also use `global` to manage your top windows in the global namespace.

Like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def child_window(window):
    window.geometry("{}x{}".format(root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height()))

def window_one():
    childwindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
    childwindow.title("title window one")
    child_window(childwindow)

def window_two():
    childwindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
    childwindow.title("title window two")
    child_window(childwindow)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")
# I added this delay due to an issue tkinter has with reading the root size before the mainloop has had a change to fully load the root window.
root.after(1000, window_one)
root.after(1000, window_two)

root.mainloop()
```

For an OOP approach see this example:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Example(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("500x300")
        self.after(1000, self.window_one)
        self.after(1000, self.window_two)

    def child_window(self, window):
        print("{}x{}".format(self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height()))
        window.geometry("{}x{}".format(self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height()))

    def window_one(self):
        childwindow = tk.Toplevel(self)
        childwindow.title("title window one")
        self.child_window(childwindow)

    def window_two(self):
        childwindow = tk.Toplevel(self)
        childwindow.title("title window two")
        self.child_window(childwindow)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Example().mainloop()
```

Comment: You could also keep the dimensions in the `child_window` function and call `child_window(root)` right after the creation of `root` to give all windows the same size.